# How to resolve memoryError when using multiprocessing module in python?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, gpu, cpu

What is the most efficient way in python to find the first set of integer values that satisfy the following equation:

```
a^{x} + b^{y} = c^{z}
```

assuming *a, b, c* are positive integers larger than 100 and *x, y, z* are positive integers larger than 10.

**Hint:**

Even using multiprocessing module of python on the CPU and GPU provided by Kaggle, I am getting memoryErrors.

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array, RawArray
import pprint
import numpy as np
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=41, compact=True)

MAXIMUM_INT: int = 30
answers = {'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': [], 'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []}

exponent_range = np.arange(10, MAXIMUM_INT + 1)
base_range = np.arange(100, MAXIMUM_INT + 1)

A_range = B_range = C_range = base_range.tolist()
x_range = y_range = z_range = exponent_range.tolist()

combinatorics = [A_range, B_range, C_range, x_range, y_range, z_range]
iteration = list(itertools.product(*combinatorics))

dim1 = dim2 = dim3 = MAXIMUM_INT
dim4 = dim5 = dim6 = MAXIMUM_INT - 2

test1 = np.zeros(dim1)
test2 = np.zeros(dim2)
test3 = np.zeros(dim3)
test4 = np.zeros(dim4)
test5 = np.zeros(dim5)
test6 = np.zeros(dim6)

def init(A: int, B: int, C: int, x: int, y: int, z: int):
    global test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6
    test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6 = A, B, C, x, y, z


def conditionalAssert(A: int, B: int, C: int, x: int, y: int, z: int):
    test1 = RawArray("i", dim1)
    test2 = RawArray("i", dim2)
    test3 = RawArray("i", dim3)
    test4 = RawArray("i", dim4)
    test5 = RawArray("i", dim5)
    test6 = RawArray("i", dim6)

    t1 = np.frombuffer(test1, dtype=int)
    t2 = np.frombuffer(test2, dtype=int)
    t3 = np.frombuffer(test3, dtype=int)
    t4 = np.frombuffer(test4, dtype=int)
    t5 = np.frombuffer(test5, dtype=int)
    t6 = np.frombuffer(test6, dtype=int)

    cond1 = (int(A**x + B**y) == int(C**z))
    if cond1:
        answers['A'].append(A)
        answers['B'].append(B)
        answers['C'].append(C)
        answers['x'].append(x)
        answers['y'].append(y)
        answers['z'].append(z)
        return A, B, C, x, y, z
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    relevantArray = Array('i', dim1 * dim2 * dim3 * dim4 * dim5 * dim6)
    A = B = C = x = y = z = relevantArray
    pool = Pool(processes=5, initializer=init, initargs=(A, B, C, x, y, z))
    for object_returned_from_conditionalAssert in pool.starmap(conditionalAssert, iteration):
        if object_returned_from_conditionalAssert:
            e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6 = object_returned_from_conditionalAssert
            answers['A'].append(e1)
            answers['B'].append(e2)
            answers['C'].append(e3)
            answers['x'].append(e4)
            answers['y'].append(e5)
            answers['z'].append(e6)

    pp.pprint(answers)
```